# React function and "this"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I know about "this" binding and all other stuff here, except one thing. I can't understand how "this" is not undefined in the first call, but second?

P.S. I know about function reference and that in the first case it's executing function but in the second case returning reference.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = "MyComponent";
    // this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.name);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick()}>click 1</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>click 2</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: By writing `onClick={this.handleClick()}` you are invoking the `this.handleClick` function directly on render, and it evaluates to `onClick={undefined}`. That's why clicking on the `click 1` button doesn't do anything. [This is a great read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context) on why `this` behaves like it does in the `click 2` button case.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question text itself. Questions should make sense even if the link breaks in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first line

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick()}>click 1</button>
```

`this.handleClick()` will be executed in the `render` function of `App` component (which is a `class` by itself) while the component is being rendered in virtual DOM. So by the time of execution, `handleClick` function will be defined in the execution context which is `App` class.

In the second line

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>click 1</button>
```

`this.handleClick` is attached to the DOM and will execute from the DOM's context when click event happens and the execution will look for handleClick in the DOM's context and will be `undefined`.

There are two ways to circumvent this

1. `bind` the method to the class as you did.
2. Pass in an anonymous function which will execute without DOM's context and by default be bound to invoker's context.

like this

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>click 1</button>
```